# FullCalendar RenderEvent Not working in version 3.9.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

i'm trying to upgrade my fullCalendar version to the latest ( 3.9.0 ) but i can't seams to make the renderEvent function work. The event simply does not render. I'm also using the latest version of the scheduler plugin ( 1.9.3 )

I tried adding events using the `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true)` like I used to, but now it does not seams to work.
I also tried `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', event)` followed by `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEventSources')` nothing seams to be working.

Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//Calendar option
const LOCALE_DEFAULT = 'fr';
const TIMEZONE_DEFAULT = 'local';
const IGNORE_TIMEZONE_DEFAULT = false;
const HEIGHT_DEFAULT = 'auto';
const DROPPABLE_DEFAULT = true;
const ALL_DAY_DEFAULT_DEFAULT = false;
const ALL_DAY_DEFAULT = false;
const ALL_DAY_SLOT_DEFAULT = false;
const TIME_EVENT_DURATION_DEFAULT = '03:00:00';
const SELECTABLE_DEFAULT = true;
const SLOT_EVENT_OVERLAPP_DEFAULT = false;
const SELECT_HELPER_DEFAULT = false;
const EVENT_RESOURCE_EDITABLE_DEFAULT = false;
const PUBLISHED = true;
const SCHEDULER_LICENCE = 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives';
let events =  [{"id":2,"title":"test","start":"2018-03-18T15:30:00.000Z","end":"2018-03-18T19:30:00-04:00","creationDate":"2018-03-18 14:55:25","resourceFullName":"testRessource","resourceId":3,"type":"shift"}];
let resources = [{
 fullname: "resource 1",
  id: 1
},
{
 fullname: "resource 3",
  id:3
}]

            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                locale: LOCALE_DEFAULT,
                timezone: TIMEZONE_DEFAULT,
                ignoreTimezone: IGNORE_TIMEZONE_DEFAULT,
                slotDuration: '00:30:00',
                height: HEIGHT_DEFAULT,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'timelineDay, weekCustom' + /*, timelineWeek */', month, agendaDay'
                },
                buttonText: {
                    today: "today",
                    timelineDay: "timelineDay",
                    timelineWeek: "timelineWeek",
                    month: "month",
                    agendaDay: "agenda"
                },
                views: {
                    weekCustom: {
                        type: 'timeline',
                        timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
                        buttonText: 'Semaine',
                        displayEventEnd: true,
                        duration: {week: 1},
                        slotDuration: {days: 1}
                    }
                },
                defaultView: "weekCustom",
                lang: 'fr'/*$filter('translate')('language')*/,
                scrollTime: "08:00:00",
                resourceAreaWidth: "220px",
                events: events,
                editable: true,
                droppable: DROPPABLE_DEFAULT,
                allDayDefault: ALL_DAY_DEFAULT_DEFAULT,
                allDay: ALL_DAY_DEFAULT,
                allDaySlot: ALL_DAY_SLOT_DEFAULT,
                defaultTimedEventDuration: TIME_EVENT_DURATION_DEFAULT,
                resourceLabelText: "resources",
                schedulerLicenseKey: SCHEDULER_LICENCE,
                selectable: SELECTABLE_DEFAULT,
                slotEventOverlap: SLOT_EVENT_OVERLAPP_DEFAULT,
                selectHelper: SELECT_HELPER_DEFAULT,
                eventResourceEditable: EVENT_RESOURCE_EDITABLE_DEFAULT,
                resources:  resources,
                select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {
                let event = {
                  start: start,
                  end: end,
                  title: "test"
                  };
                  //$("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [event]);
                  //$("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEventSources',  [event]);
                  //true for stick events
                  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);
                },
                eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
                },
                eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
                },
                eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                },
                viewRender: function (view) {
                },
                loading: function (bool, view) {
                }
            });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.3/scheduler.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.3/scheduler.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar">
</div>
```

P.S. use the timeline day for a more efficient test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, and creates the event quite happily - try it: select a time period (in any view), remember the date/time you chose, and then go to your "month" view. You will see the created event in the timeslot you selected.

The problem comes when you try to *view* the event in a view which uses resources. Your code does not specify a resourceId for the new event. Therefore, fullCalendar has no idea which resource to show the event on, and so cannot display it at all in any resource-aware view.

To fix this, simply take the resourceId supplied in the `resourceObj` parameter of the `select` callback, and include it in your new event object:

```
let event = {
  start: start,
  end: end,
  title: "test",
  resourceId: resourceObj.id
};
```

P.S. you should also run "unselect" after the call to "renderEvent", otherwise the timeslot chosen will remain highlighted on the calendar behind the created event (until or unless the user clicks elsewhere). In some views this is more obvious than others, but it doesn't look right. The command is simply:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('unselect');
```

Comment: Just to clear everything out, This was the answer to the problem in my answer. however, it was not on my actual app. Problem was, I imported a `min` version and a normal version of the scheduler plugin. Using grunt to generate my HTML. ADyson did fix the problem on my question so i will leave his answer as the correct one.

Comment: The output was the same though.